# PrimeNG Message & Toast worked in Component but not in Service

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a working message alert in component using PrimeNG framework.

@Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-client',
    templateUrl: './client.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client.component.css'],
    providers: [MessageService],
})
```

Constructor

```
private msg: MessageService,
```

Component method

```
this.msg.add({severity:'success', summary: 'Success Message', detail:'Order submitted'});
```

But once i moved to a service's method and include the 'ClientService' in component

```
import { ClientService } from '../../../shared/services/client.service'
```

Import message in client.service.ts

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

method in ClientService

```
...
this.msg.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail: msg});
...
```

There ain't any error messages, also no toast prompt. I tried to understand the official doc
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/toast

> A message is displayed using a MessageService, make sure your
>   component has an injectable MessageService defined as a provider
>   otherwise Toast cannot be utilized.

But i have no idea how to 'inject' messageservice.

sample project here https://stackblitz.com/edit/d-toast

Comment: remove     providers: [MessageService], from client component

Comment: @GouravGarg it doesn't work even removed from component level. I think it needs to inject a 'provider' into service, or make the 'provivder' global but i can't figure out the correct code :)

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: sample provided

Comment: Based on your provided Sample, as @GouravGarg mentioned: Remove Line 11 from AppComponent and it will work.
[Forked Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/d-toast-hnktsr)

Consider making your Helper Service treeshakable with @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'}) and removed it from the providers Array in your AppModule.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-client',
    templateUrl: './client.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./client.component.css'],
    providers: [ClientService],
})
```

Do not forget on AppClientComponent.html

```
<p-toast></p-toast>
```

In App.module

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';  providers:
...
providers: [MessageService]
```

In your client.service

```
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

injecting just means in your `ClientService` you should have this:

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}
```

and in your component you should add `ClientService` in the providers array

Comment: sure i did import { ClientService } from '../../../shared/services/client.service' into Client component, else will hit error can't load method under ClientService.Method()... My situation is  the service included in client component, the client service's method executed without error. Just the "Toas" doesn't pop up :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass messageservice from component and use it into service.

app.component.ts

```
constructor(private toastService: ToastService) {}

this.toastService.ShowMessage(this).subscribe(() => {});
```

client-service.ts

```
ShowMessage(instance: any){
  instance.toastService.ShowToast();
}
```

toast-service.ts

```
constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

ShowToast(){
   this.messageService.add({severity:'success', summary:'Success', detail: msg});
}
```